# Is there a free open source font for programming that I can install from Synaptic (Ubuntu) and looks like Monaco?

Tags: ubuntu, fonts

I've been a fan of Monaco when I was a Windows user I would like to know if there's a free open alternative to that font (and possibly available in Synaptic Package Manager).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a copy of the font you could just install it manually...

press alt+F2 (Run Application) then type: `gksudo nautilus /usr/share/fonts/truetype` to open the proper directory as superuser, create a new directory there & put whatever fonts you have in. After that you'll need to rebuild the font directory, to do that hit alt+F2 again & check off 'Run in Terminal' and enter: `sudo fc-cache -f -v`  Once that's done running you should be good to go.

Identifont offers alternatives to any font you're looking for too, so check out : http://www.identifont.com/similar?1O2 the list of similar fonts is on the left.

Looks like you can also get monaco free at: http://www.fonts101.com/fonts/view/Uncategorized/51239/Monaco.aspx